# Limit Contact Form 7 hook to specific form

Tags: conditional-tags, plugin-contact-form-7

I'm using a Contact Form 7 filter to take action after the email is sent. How can I limit this action to only one form? There are multiple forms on different pages, and I don't want this action to run after every form, only one specific form.

I tried limiting the action to the page where the form is using an if clause, but then the "action" doesn't complete. Once I remove the if clause, then the action works.

```
function foo() {

   if(is_page('bar') {

     // some action
    }
}
add_action( 'wpcf7_mail_sent', 'foo', 1 );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You know the id of the form from the shortcode, you can do stuff just for that particular form. Here's some sample code for that, just replace `$myform_id` with your form id:

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_mail_sent', 'wp190913_wpcf7' );

/**
 * Do stuff for my contact form form. This function shouldn't return aything
 * 
 * @param WPCF7_ContactForm $contact_form wpcf7 object, passed by refference
 */
function wp190913_wpcf7( $contact_form ) {

    // Not my desired form? bail
    if ( $contact_form->id !== $myform_id )
        return;

    // Do stuff for my contact form
}
```

Comment: For anyone still running into this post, `$contact_form->id` is not accessible anymore so use `$contact_form->id()` instead